# solve $\cos y \sin(2x) dx + (\cos^2y - \cos^2x)dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

any ideas on how to approach this ?

Few observations :

1) not separable even after simplifying trig

2) not exact

I am thinking substitution may work, still trying... appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

- try to find an integrating factor of the form $f(y)$,
  i.e., you want to find $f(y)$ such that 
  $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}  \cos y \sin(2x)\,f(y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}
  (\cos^2 y -\cos^2 x)\, f(y)$$
  which simplifies to
  $$ -\sin y \,f(y) +\cos y\, f'(y) = f(y).$$

Comment: Oh I am doing this method for the first time, do i get $\sin(2x)[-\sin y f(y) + f'(y) \cos y] = f(y)*\sin(2x)$ ?

Comment: Got it xD il be able to finish rest of the problem :) thanks a lot !

Comment: @GaneshTadi: yes, now divide by $\sin(2x)$. The resulting equation only involves $y$. In the end $f(y)$ can be solved, e.g., by separation.